# How to deselect a jquery mobile 1.4 selected option?

Tags: jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

I've got a `<select>` on a page, and in certain cases I need to reset the value the user has selected. I know how to do that on a normal select element, but I'm using jQuery Mobile and usual method don't work. I've even tried a few other methods found online, but I keep getting errors or obtaining nothing.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with resetting a select which has been taken over by jQuery Mobile (jQM from now on), as it does a pretty good work on doing a mess of it.

First thing, you need the right way to access it.
When you declare a select in your mark-up, at runtime jQM wrap it into a div (inside another div, but just ignore it) and prepone a span to the select, this way:

```
<div>
    <span class="a_class"></span>
    <select id="an_id" class="a_class">
    </select>
</div>
```

Problem here is, jQM is best used by class and not by ID (as it make a huge mess even of them), so if you do things jQM's way...you end up selecting the span and calling functions over it: this not only does not reset the combo, but gives you a nice exception too.

Solutions:

1. Use id for selecting selects with selectors (pun intended)
2. Keep using classes and use this selector: `$('a_class').filter('select')`
3. Keep using classes and use this selector: `$('a_class')[1]`

The first one is risky in the context of jQM, the third one relies on the fact that the selector will always selects the span first and then the select (and that underlying structure will always be this way). I honestly prefer the second approach, as I think it's safer.

Once found a way to <strike>select</strike> access the select you can deselect it's selected option, but the two more obvious way to do it will not work:

1. There is no functionality in jQM to deselect a selected option
2. jQM's select do not keep itself in sync with the HTML select

**Solution**

You need to do it in two steps: first, remove the selection on the HTML select (accessing it by class); then, request the jQM's select to sincronyze with the HMTL's one:

```
$('.a_class').filter('select')[0].selectedIndex = -1;
$('.a_class').filter('select').selectmenu('refresh');
```

Comment: I lost a couple of days trying to understand the damn thing, tried a lot of solution from SE and elsewhere (most marked as "accepted", none working in my case), and finally came to this by putting pieces together. Post it hoping it will spare some stress and wasted time for someone else.